# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: cypher_parser_version

Tags: java, scala, neo4j

I am getting below exception while starting NeoServer-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: cypher_parser_version
```

Comment: Please, show more StackTrace

Comment: This usually indicates incompatible versions of libraries.Try using the latest versions of lib.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of exception generally indicates accidentally mixing Java Jars from different Neo4j versions.

If you've downloaded the .tar.gz server from Neo4j.org, make sure you've not made changes to the jar files or added any external jars into the server.

If you are starting the server from inside a java application, go over your dependencies and make extra sure you have no version mixups or multiple versions of some jar. You can dump the whole dependency graph if you use Maven using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```